# document.getElementById not working / Display

Tags: javascript, document, getelementbyid

What am i doing wrong here?

Here is the code:

```
<script>
  var points = 1000;
  document.getElementById(pointsdisplay).innerHTML = "Points:" + points;
</script>
<p id="pointsdisplay"></p>
```

I want to display the points on the website. I really don't understand why this isn't working.

Note that I put the script tag inside of the HTML code. Later, I will make an external js file and put everything in there.

Comment: Put the id inside getElementbyId inside double quotes.

Comment: I noticed that I forgot to put "" inside of when I was calling the id of pointsdisplay, after fixing this, it still doesn't do anything PLZ help!

Comment: Quotes around getElementById("pointsdisplay")

Comment: Without quotes around it `pointsdisplay` is a variable. Since you haven't defined a variable called `pointsdisplay`, its value is `undefined`, so `getElementById` is looking for an element named `"undefined"`, not one named `"pointsdisplay"`. Also, the JS is running before the `p` exists, so it won't find it even if you put the quotes in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two mistakes here,

1. You need to surround id with `"` (Double Quotes)
2. You should put script tag after the `dom` element is created, else it may execute before the actual `dom` is created. Even if you keep js code in a separate file, make sure you write it after your `dom`, just before the `body` tag ends.

So your code should be like,

```
<p id="pointsdisplay"></p> 
<script>
    var points = 1000;
    document.getElementById('pointsdisplay').innerHTML = "Points:" + points;
</script>
```

Working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/errhunter/f3s1km1v/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the `DOM` in HTML before the script. Like this,

```html
<p id="pointsdisplay"></p>
<script>
var points = 1000;
document.getElementById("pointsdisplay").innerHTML = "Points:" + points;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be having the element id between quotations and besides, it is recommended to have the DOM element before the script tag.

```html
<p id="pointsdisplay"></p>
<script>
var points = 1000;
document.getElementById('pointsdisplay').innerHTML = "Points:" + points;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I see two problems here.

The first is that the document.getElementById needs to be given a String. You could use: `document.getElementById("pointsDisplay")`.

Secondly, I think you will need to put the script underneath the p. The browser will execute the script as soon as it hits the script tag.

Answer (score 0):

The id name should be in string and the HTML tag should loaded first

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!--you have two options -->
<p id="pointsdisplay"></p>
<!--Html tag should be loaded first -->
<script>
var points = 1000;
// the id name should be in string 
document.getElementById("pointsdisplay").innerHTML = "Points:" + points;
</script>

<!-- second option  jquery ready function, so that would wait for the document to be loaded then execute the script -->
<script>
var points = 1000;
$(document).ready(function(){
document.getElementById("pointsdisplay1").innerHTML = "Points:" + points;
});
</script>
<p id="pointsdisplay1"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

All of the other answers here are correct however I would like to point out that if you use the DOMContentLoaded event the script will wait until the DOM has loaded before executing.

Eg.

```html
<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
        var points = 1000;
        document.getElementById("pointsdisplay").innerHTML = "Points:" + points;
    });
</script>
<p id="pointsdisplay"></p>
```